# JavaFX tableview showing only last row of data repeatedly from MySQL database

Tags: mysql, javafx, tableview

I have a windows application where I want to populate my table of from MySQL database. I have written the code below to get data in table. I am able to get the database but while adding the rows in table it shows only last row (repeatedly as much the rows of in MySQL) from MySQL database.

```
public class ShowDatabase{  
 private static ObservableList<UserMaster> row;
 private static ObservableList<String> col;
 public static void buildData(TableView<UserMaster> tableview){
     Connection c;
     String SQL = "SELECT * from user_info";
     UserMaster cm = new UserMaster();
     try{
     String colHeading[]={"Name","Course","e-mail","City"};
     col = FXCollections.observableArrayList(colHeading);
     row= FXCollections.observableArrayList();
     c= DBConnection.connect();  
     ResultSet rs = c.createStatement().executeQuery(SQL);

     TableColumn<UserMaster,String> colName = new TableColumn<UserMaster, String>(col.get(0));
     colName.setMinWidth(200);
     colName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<UserMaster,String>("name"));

     TableColumn<UserMaster, String> colCourse = new TableColumn<UserMaster, String>(col.get(1));
     colCourse.setMinWidth(200);
     colCourse.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<UserMaster,String>("course"));

     TableColumn<UserMaster, String> colEmail = new TableColumn<UserMaster, String>(col.get(2));
     colEmail.setMinWidth(200);
     colEmail.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<UserMaster,String>("email"));

     TableColumn<UserMaster, String> colCity = new TableColumn<UserMaster, String>(col.get(3));
     colCity.setMinWidth(200);
     colCity.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<UserMaster,String>("city"));

     tableview.getColumns().addAll(colName,colCourse,colEmail,colCity);
             //colMobile,colEmail,colDoj,colCity);

     while(rs.next()){

             ObservableList<UserMaster> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
             cm.name.set(rs.getString("name"));
             cm.course.set(rs.getString("course_name"));
             cm.email.set(rs.getString("email"));
             cm.city.set(rs.getString("city"));
             row.add(cm);


             System.out.println(row.get(0).getName());
         }
         tableview.setItems(row);
     }catch(SQLException sqex){
         sqex.printStackTrace();
          System.out.println("Error on Building Data"); 
     }
 }
```

}

Code to build table (Application):

```
public class DisplayDatabase extends Application{  
   @Override  
   public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {  
     stage.setFullScreen(false);  
     TableView tableview;  
     //TableView  
     tableview = new TableView();  
     DisplayDatabase.buildData(tableview);  
     //Adding GridPane  
     GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();  
     gridPane.setPadding(new Insets(20,20,20,20));  
     gridPane.setHgap(5);  
     gridPane.setVgap(5);  
     //Main Scene  
     Scene scene = new Scene(tableview);      
     stage.setScene(scene);  
     stage.show();  
   }  
   public static void main(String args[]){  
     launch(args);  
   }  
 }
```

And the class to format Observable List:

```
public class UserMaster{    
   public SimpleStringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
   public SimpleStringProperty course = new SimpleStringProperty();
   public SimpleIntegerProperty mobile = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
   public SimpleStringProperty email = new SimpleStringProperty();
   public ObjectProperty<Date> doj = new SimpleObjectProperty<Date>();
   public SimpleStringProperty city = new SimpleStringProperty();


   public String getName() {
      return name.get();
   }

   public String getEmail() {
      return email.get();
   }

   public String getCity() {
      return city.get();
   }

   public String getCourse() {
      return course.get();
   }


}
```

Though I have 2 unique rows of data but it is showing only last row (same data) form database table repeatedly.
Here is the picture attachment for more clarity about problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create new `UserMaster` on every iteration:

```
while(rs.next()){

         UserMaster cm = new UserMaster();
         cm.name.set(rs.getString("name"));
         cm.course.set(rs.getString("course_name"));
         cm.email.set(rs.getString("email"));
         cm.city.set(rs.getString("city"));
         row.add(cm);
 }
 tableview.setItems(row);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(rs.next()){
     cm.name.set(rs.getString("name"));
     cm.course.set(rs.getString("course_name"));
     cm.email.set(rs.getString("email"));
     cm.city.set(rs.getString("city"));
     row.add(new UserMaster(name,course,email,city));
}
tableview.setItems(row);
```

try this :)